# purrr loop: Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `combined_data`. x `x` and `y` must share the same src, set `copy` = TRUE (may be slow)

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I tried to create a reproducible example but, frustratingly this actually works:

```
my_mtcars <- mtcars %>% 
  rownames_to_column('car') %>% 
  group_by(vs) %>% 
  nest

my_mtcars <- my_mtcars %>% 
  mutate(lhs = map(.x = data, ~ .x %>% select(car:drat))) %>% 
  mutate(rhs = map(.x = data, ~ .x %>% select(car, wt:carb) %>% rename(model = car))) %>% 
  mutate(together_again = map2(.x = lhs, .y = rhs, ~ inner_join(.x, .y, by = c('car' = 'model'))))
```

The above works but shows in a nutshell what I'm trying to do with my real data. My actual data frame which includes list columns fails to mutate with an inner join and I'm hoping that by describing and showing some anonymised data here someone may be able to advise.

My data frame `pdata`:

```
data
# A tibble: 104 x 7
   MONETIZATION_WEEK_COHORT data                   cut_off clv_obj          model            prediction       training_period_metrics
   <date>                   <list>                   <int> <list>           <list>           <list>           <list>                 
 1 2020-03-30               <tibble [214,509 × 9]>       7 <named list [2]> <named list [2]> <named list [2]> <tibble [7,328 × 3]>   
 2 2020-03-30               <tibble [214,509 × 9]>       8 <named list [2]> <named list [2]> <named list [2]> <tibble [7,328 × 3]>   
 3 2020-04-06               <tibble [496,626 × 9]>       7 <named list [2]> <named list [2]> <named list [2]> <tibble [20,060 × 3]>  
 4 2020-04-06               <tibble [496,626 × 9]>       8 <named list [2]> <named list [2]> <named list [2]> <tibble [20,060 × 3]>  
 5 2020-04-13               <tibble [595,775 × 9]>       7 <named list [2]> <named list [2]> <named list [2]> <tibble [25,816 × 3]>  
 6 2020-04-13               <tibble [595,775 × 9]>       8 <named list [2]> <named list [2]> <named list [2]> <tibble [25,816 × 3]>  
 7 2020-04-20               <tibble [548,436 × 9]>       7 <named list [2]> <named list [2]> <named list [2]> <tibble [22,161 × 3]>  
 8 2020-04-20               <tibble [548,436 × 9]>       8 <named list [2]> <named list [2]> <named list [2]> <tibble [22,161 × 3]>  
 9 2020-04-27               <tibble [529,507 × 9]>       7 <named list [2]> <named list [2]> <named list [2]> <tibble [21,113 × 3]>  
10 2020-04-27               <tibble [529,507 × 9]>       8 <named list [2]> <named list [2]> <named list [2]> <tibble [21,113 × 3]>
```

I'm trying to join prediction with training period metrics for each row. Here's what a sample of those two fields look like, they are both data frames:

The `.y` field in map2 below:

```
 pdata$prediction[[1]]$result %>% head(2) %>% glimpse
Rows: 2
Columns: 11
$ Id                      <chr> "123abc", "def456"
$ period.first            <date> 2020-05-21, 2020-05-21
$ period.last             <date> 2020-08-26, 2020-08-26
$ period.length           <int> 14, 14
$ actual.x                <int> 0, 0
$ actual.total.spending   <dbl> 0, 0
$ PAlive                  <dbl> 0.72933712, 0.05683547
$ CET                     <dbl> 19.2692978, 0.1285307
$ DERT                    <dbl> 13.37550762, 0.08921192
$ predicted.mean.spending <dbl> 839.648, 1017.683
$ predicted.CLV           <dbl> 11230.71800, 90.78944
```

The `.x` field in map2 below:

```
pdata$training_period_metrics[[1]] %>% head(2) %>% glimpse
Rows: 2
Columns: 3
$ S              <chr> "abc123", "def456"
$ Transactions   <int> 40, 3
$ Total_Spending <dbl> 14660, 1797
```

I'm trying to join these into a data frame as a new column:

```
pdata %>% mutate(combined_data = map2(.x = training_period_metrics, .y = prediction, ~ inner_join(.x, .y$result, by = c('S' = 'Id'))))
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `combined_data`.
x `x` and `y` must share the same src, set `copy` = TRUE (may be slow).
ℹ Input `combined_data` is `map2(...)`.
```

How can I join `prediction$result` with `training_period_metrics` within my purrr loop?

Comment: Please check if all the elements in the rhs or lhs have data i.e. if i do `my_mtcars$rhs[[2]] <- NULL;  my_mtcars %>%  mutate(together_again = map2(.x = lhs, .y = rhs, ~ inner_join(.x, .y, by = c('car' = 'model'))))#
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `together_again`.
✖ `x` and `y` must share the same src, set `copy` = TRUE (may be slow).`

Comment: Aha! Yes, some of them are NULL

Comment: If you correct for those elements by skipping them, it would be work.  It is not clear what kind of conditions you want for those cases

Comment: In the case of a NULL, I'd like to make the new df NULL or NA (I don't understand which is best here) else I would like to do the join

Comment: You can try the solution posted below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use a condition to do the join only if both `.x` and `.y` are not `NULL` or else return NULL

```
my_mtcars %>%
    mutate(together_again = map2(.x = lhs, .y = rhs,
  ~ if(is.null(unlist(.x))|is.null(unlist(.y))) list(NULL) else
        inner_join(.x, .y, by = c('car' = 'model'))))
```

Comment: I should be able to do this on my own but I'm trying and failing to modify your solution to ifelse() syntax. Is that doable here?

Comment: @user14328853 `ifelse` is not appropriate for this case.  It is vectorized to do for all elements, but in our case, the elements i.e. data.frames are inside a list, so `if/else` would be better.

Comment: Or another option is to wrap with `tryCatch` and return a value when there is an error

Comment: I took a look at the docs for tryCatch in r. I find it tricky to follow. My actual code `%>% mutate(combined_data = map2(.x = training_period_metrics, .y = prediction, ~ tryCatch(inner_join(.x, .y$result, by = c('S' = 'Id')))))` gives the same error. Should I ask a fresh question?

Comment: @user14328853 This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12193779/how-to-write-trycatch-in-r) may help you in writing `tryCatch`.  In your code you have to specify the `error = `